# Dataframe name not shown when selecting variables in PowerBi

Tags: r, powerbi

My RStudio is active.But when I select variables in my powerBI, I can not see the dataframe name as it shoud be. I get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDghM.png)

Any help ?

Comment: # indicates the start of a comment which will be ignored by any R interpreter. Here is a free book to learn data analysis with R: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.